# multidimensional list remove duplicates only for that level

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am trying to build a treeview of crates from a program called Serato, how they build their crates in their program is by the files in a folder, however the issue is that you can have multiple internal and external hard drives with folders carrying the same names, also sub folders can also have the same name as the previous parent folder.

For example a folder can look like this;

```
C:/Music%%House.crate
C:/Music%%House%%Chicago.crate
C:/Music%%House%%Garage.crate
C:/Music%%Hip-Hop%%Classic.crate
C:/Music%%Hip-Hop%%Remixes.crate
C:/Music%%Hip-Hop%%New.crate
C:/Music%%House%%Hip-Hop%%House Remixes.crate
C:/Videos%%House.crate
C:/Videos%%House%%Chicago.crate
C:/House%%Unsorted.crate
Hip-Hop%%Unsorted.crate
C:/Hip-Hop%%Wedding.crate
```

As you can see nested inside are crates with the same name as children.
Now I can have another folder on another drive, identical but maybe with another added folder like;

```
D:/Music%%House.crate
D:/Music%%House%%Chicago.crate
D:/Music%%House%%Garage.crate
D:/Music%%Hip-Hop%%Classic.crate
D:/Music%%Hip-Hop%%Remixes.crate
D:/Music%%Hip-Hop%%New.crate
D:/Music%%Hip-Hop%%Transitions.crate
D:/Music%%House%%Hip-Hop%%House Remixes.crate
D:/Videos%%House.crate
D:/Videos%%House%%Chicago.crate
D:/House%%Unsorted.crate
D:/Hip-Hop%%Unsorted.crate
D:/Hip-Hop%%Wedding.crate
```

What I need to do is get this in a WPF treeview to look like this;

```
Hip-Hop
--Unsorted
--Wedding
House
--Unsorted
Music
--House
----Chichago
----Garage
----Hip-Hop
------House Remixes
--Hip-Hop
----Classic
----Remixes
----New
Videos
--House
----Chicago
```

Path strings look like this:

```
C:/Music%%House%%Hip-Hop%%House Remixes.crate
```

Here lies my problem I don't know where to begin to populate the custom list in order to add these avoiding duplicate names in certain levels of children, but retain and add the volume to the custom list.Hopefully I explained this well, I am a beginner at this.

Updated with Bionic Code's Answer, still getting an error.

```
public class FileSystemItem : IEquatable<FileSystemItem>
{
  public FileSystemItem(string name, FileSystemItem parent)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Parent = parent;
    this.Children = new List<FileSystemItem>();
    this.Volumes = new List<DriveInfo>();
  }

  public string Name { get; }
  public FileSystemItem Parent { get; }
  public IList<FileSystemItem> Children { get; }
  public IList<DriveInfo> Volumes { get; }

  public bool Equals(FileSystemItem? other) => (this.Name, this.Parent).Equals((other.Name, other.Parent));
}





if (patsh.Count > 0)
{


    var treeLevelIndex = new List<Dictionary<string, FileSystemItem>>();

    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
       FileSystemItem parentFileSystemItem = null;
                    int level = 0;

       string pathRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
       DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo(pathRoot);
       string pathWithoutRoot = path.Substring(drive.Name.Length);

       foreach (string directoryName in pathWithoutRoot.Split(new char[] { '%', '%' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
       {
            
          if (treeLevelIndex.Count == level)
          {
             treeLevelIndex.Add(new Dictionary<string, FileSystemItem>());
          }

          var levelIndex = treeLevelIndex[level];

          // Check if path segment already exists (merge)
          if (levelIndex.TryGetValue(directoryName, out FileSystemItem indexedParent))
          {
             // Don't add duplicates
             if (!indexedParent.Volumes.Any(volume => volume.Name.Equals(drive.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal)))
             {
                 indexedParent.Volumes.Add(drive);
             }

             parentFileSystemItem = indexedParent;
             level++;
             continue;
          }

          /* Create index entry for the current level */

          var childFileSystemItem = new FileSystemItem(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(directoryName), parentFileSystemItem);
          childFileSystemItem.Volumes.Add(drive);

          // Tree leaf. Don't add duplicates. 
          // Does not need to be indexed as it will not hold child nodes.
          if (Path.HasExtension(directoryName))
          {
             if (!parentFileSystemItem?.Children.Contains(childFileSystemItem) ?? false)
             {
                parentFileSystemItem.Children.Add(childFileSystemItem);
             }
          }
          else // An unindexed tree node.
          {
              parentFileSystemItem?.Children.Add(childFileSystemItem);
                            
           // THIS IS WHERE THE EXPECTION UNHANDLED breaks at (below)                                
              levelIndex.Add(childFileSystemItem.Name, childFileSystemItem);
              parentFileSystemItem = childFileSystemItem;
          }
          level++;
      }
  }

  List<FileSystemItem> treeViewSource = treeLevelIndex.First().Values.ToList();
                
               

  TvCrates.ItemsSource = treeViewSource;

}
```

As shown in remarks above the error occurs in this area;

```
else // An unindexed tree node.
{
    parentFileSystemItem?.Children.Add(childFileSystemItem);
                                         
    levelIndex.Add(childFileSystemItem.Name, childFileSystemItem);
    parentFileSystemItem = childFileSystemItem;
}
level++;
```

by

```
levelIndex.Add(childFileSystemItem.Name, childFileSystemItem);
```

With the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'
```

Here is an actual listing of the paths: (changed paths file)
https://file.io/pI6WqAIgjS4l

Comment: have you tried using `.GroupBy` on the list, with a `.Distinct`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to build the tree level by level, starting from the root (and not the leaf). You must start from the drive name. Then use Dictionary as lookup table to efficiently identify and merge duplicates.

To identify the duplicates, it is essential to let the data model implement `IEquatable`. Alternatively implement a custom `IEqualityComparer`:

```cs
public class FileSystemItem : IEquatable<FileSystemItem>
{
  public FileSystemItem(string name, FileSystemItem parent)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Parent = parent;
    this.Children = new List<FileSystemItem>();
    this.Volumes = new List<DriveInfo>();
  }

  public string Name { get; }
  public FileSystemItem Parent { get; }
  public IList<FileSystemItem> Children { get; }
  public IList<DriveInfo> Volumes { get; }

  public bool Equals(FileSystemItem? other) 
    => (this.Name, this.Parent).Equals((other.Name, other.Parent));
}
```

The algorithm to build the tree is also very simple. This is a free example:

```cs
// Your input 
var paths = new List<string>();

// The list of lookup tables which is also the flattened tree structure. 
// Each tree level is equivalent to a path segment (directory).
// Each level has its own lookup table to allow the same name on each level.       
var treeLevelIndex = new List<Dictionary<string, FileSystemItem>>();
      
foreach (string path in paths)
{
  if (!Path.HasExtension(path))
  {
    continue;  
  }

  FileSystemItem parentFileSystemItem = null;
  int level = 0;

  string pathRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
  DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo(pathRoot);
  int crateStartIndex = Math.Max(path.LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar), path.LastIndexOf(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar));
  string pathWithoutRoot = crateStartIndex > 0 
    ? path.Substring(crateStartIndex) 
    : path;

  char[] separators =  
  { 
    '%', 
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, // '\'
    Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar // '/'
  };
  foreach (string directoryName in pathWithoutRoot.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  {
    if (treeLevelIndex.Count == level)
    {
      treeLevelIndex.Add(new Dictionary<string, FileSystemItem>());
    }

    var levelIndex = treeLevelIndex[level];

    // Check if path segment already exists (merge)
    if (levelIndex.TryGetValue(directoryName, out FileSystemItem indexedParent))
    {
      // Don't add duplicates
      if (!indexedParent.Volumes.Any(volume => volume.Name.Equals(drive.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal)))
      {
        indexedParent.Volumes.Add(drive);
      }

      parentFileSystemItem = indexedParent;
      level++;
      continue;
    }

    /* Create index entry for the current level */

    var pathWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(directoryName);
    var childFileSystemItem = new FileSystemItem(pathWithoutExtension, parentFileSystemItem);
    childFileSystemItem.Volumes.Add(drive);

    // Tree leaf. Don't add duplicates. 
    // Does not need to be indexed as it will not hold child nodes,
    // except the node with an extension is a root node.
    if (Path.HasExtension(directoryName))
    {
      if (!parentFileSystemItem?.Children.Contains(childFileSystemItem) ?? false)
      {
        parentFileSystemItem.Children.Add(childFileSystemItem);
      }
      if (level == 0)
      {
        levelIndex.Add(directoryName, childFileSystemItem);
      }
    }
    else // An unindexed tree node.
    {
      parentFileSystemItem?.Children.Add(childFileSystemItem);
      levelIndex.Add(directoryName, childFileSystemItem);
      parentFileSystemItem = childFileSystemItem;
    }
    level++;
  }
}

List<FileSystemItem> treeViewSource = treeLevelIndex.First().Values.ToList();
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileSystemItem}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <TextBlcok Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it, however I get a Exception unhandled error, 'An Item with the same key has alreadyy been added.' at: levelIndex.Add(childFileSystemItem.Name, childFileSystemItem);

Comment: I did if (!levelIndex.ContainsKey(childFileSyystemItem.Name)) to skip the same key, however the treeview shows nothing, just 3 empty lines

Comment: I'm assuming I have to use a <HeirarchialDataTemplate>in XAML to display the list?

Comment: I have added a template example. There should be no duplicates in the Dictionary as the algorithm checks for existence using TryGetValue before adding a new entry. Make sure that IEquatable is properly implemented. Maybe you can update your question to show you IEquatable implementation and where exactly the exception is thrown and what input you have used to test it. Thank you.

Comment: Works, the only thing I am missing is the paths that don't have any children, and are just standalone.

Comment: What do you mean? It should capture every segment from root (drive) to infinite except for nested directories like c:\Videos\HipHop\... It currently only expects root folders. But I've just updated the answer and added directory separators to the string.Split parameters. The current solution should support any depth of the path.

Comment: For example there are inputs like H:_Serato_\Subcrates\under192.crate, H:_Serato_\Subcrates\Crate Trap.crate, H:_Serato_\Subcrates\NOW.crate, these do not have children and are not showing up on the treeview.

Comment: But this are not valid paths? The drive letter must followed by a slash? However, there is no reason why they won't show up? How does "H:_Serato_\Subcrates\NOW.crate" differ from "C:/Music%%House%%Hip-Hop%%House Remixes.crate"? I don't see a difference except the missing drive separator.

Comment: Or do you mean the missing "%%" separator? Have you copied the latest version? I have updated the answer 48 min ago (see my previous comment: *"[...] It currently only expects root folders. But I've just updated the answer and added directory separators to the string.Split parameters. The current solution should support any depth of the path."*).

Comment: In the actual program this is based off, it uses the filename to determine its crates, so therefore H:_Serato_\Subcrates\NOW.crate would be its own crate, with no subcrates (children), C:/Music%%House%%Hip-Hop%%House Remixes.crate, would be a main crate of Music, with a Subcrate(child) House, that also has a child Hip-Hop, and Hip-Hip has a child called House Remixes. 
The thing that matters is the filename itself for the hierarchy, and the volume for its location, folders don't matter. all the paths are located in _Serato_/SubCrates/ adding separators is not needed no need for folders

Comment: I also noticed that TEXTDOC removed the slash after the H: path, I guess textdoc needs double \\ to display correctly. I will fix it.

Comment: I see. "%%" is the delimiter to mark a child of a crate. The latest version should be able to parse the structure properly.

Comment: it does parse it, but it also includes the Serato folder name, and the Subcrate name as well in the treeview

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the rules you need to apply. If we input "H:_Serato_\Subcrates\NOW.crate", then what must be displayed and what discarded? The current algorith will create a tree like Serato->Subcrates->NOW.

Comment: *"_Serato_/SubCrates/ adding separators is not needed no need for folders"* - ok so "H:_Serato_\Subcrates\NOW.crate" must create a tree like "NOW". Truncate all the file system path segments?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out by just changing pathwithroot to Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path); and just using new char[] { '%', '%' } in the split. Now it gets all the folders correctly. I appreciate all your help you've gone above and beyond!